# VBoxManage: error: VERR_PROC_ELEVATION_REQUIRED (VirtualBox guestcontrol execute)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization

I am trying to run a program inside a Windows 7 guest VM from my Linux host:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol Win7-64bit-Pro-VM1 run --exe "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe" --verbose --username Admin1 --password "123"
```

However, since the program needs elevation, I get this error:

```
Creating guest session as user 'VM1'...
Waiting for guest session to start...
Successfully started guest session (ID 8)
Starting guest process ...
VBoxManage: error: VERR_PROC_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component GuestProcessWrap, interface IGuestProcess, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "WaitForArray(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aWaitStartFlags), gctlRunGetRemainingTime(msStart, cMsTimeout), &waitResult)" at line 1470 of file VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp
Closing guest session ...
```

I tried to disable UAC on Windows 7 guest VM, but it didn't work.

Is there a solution for this problem?

I am using VirtualBox 6.0.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an issue in bug tracker - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19459

Meanwhile, you can circumvent this error by making some other app to execute your main application. For example:

vboxmanage guestcontrol w10_1 --username user --password pass start "C:\Windows\Explorer.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\rufus-3.9.exe"

Comment: I managed to fix it by using "start" instead of "run", more info here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=94312

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem on a few systems and it turned out to be a compatibility problem with hypervisor. I disabled hypervisor in the boot configuration editor by running `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` in an command prompt as administrator (Start Menu > Type cmd > right click command prompt and select "run as Administrator")

I rebooted the system and launched the VM. The problem was resolved.

Obviously please check you are not using the services hypervisor provides or if you face problenms you can re-enable the hypervisor launch with `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`